# How can we get all the text from after the <br> tag including the <u> tag also by using the xpaths?

Tags: python, html, linux, xpath

Sample HTML :

```
<div class="apPageBottom">
   <div id="refs">References<span class="icon-search"></span></div>
   <div id="refStash">
      Medically reviewed by Joseph T. Palermo, DO; Board Certified Internal Medicine/Geriatric Medicine
      <br /><br />
      REFERENCES:<br /><br />
      Braunwald, Eugene, et al. <u>Harrisons's Principles of Internal Medicine</u>. 15th ed. McGraw-Hill, 2010.<br /><br />
      FDA.gov. Computed Tomography.
      <br /><br />
      Tramma, Simone, et al. "Helical CT Scans and Lung Cancer Screening." CDC NIOSH Science Blog. 10 Jan. 2011. 
   </div>
</div>
```

Here we are trying to get them as a list of objects by using the paths. But we are getting missed some data.

```
//div[@id='refStash']/br[following-sibling::node()[self::*|self::text()[normalize-space()]][1][self::br]]/following-sibling::br[1]//following-sibling::br[1]//following-sibling::text()
```

- We tried by using the above XPath but we are missing the `<u>` tag data
- Expected output

```
"references": [
    {
      "text": [
        "Braunwald, Eugene, et al.",
        "Harrisons's Principles of Internal Medicine. 15th ",
        "ed. McGraw-Hill, 2010." 
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": [
        "FDA.gov. Computed Tomography."
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": [
        "Tramma, Simone, et al. \"Helical CT Scans and Lung Cancer Screening.\" CDC NIOSH Science Blog. 10 Jan. 2011."
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath expressions with `LXML` (first XPath is the most secure option, last one is the less secure option) :

```
//text()[contains(.,"REFERENCES:")]/following::text()[normalize-space()][ancestor::div[position()=1 or position()=2][@id="refStash"]]
//text()[contains(.,"REFERENCES:")]/following::text()[normalize-space()][parent::div[@id="refStash"] or parent::u[parent::div[@id="refStash"]]]
//text()[contains(.,"REFERENCES:")]/following::text()[normalize-space()][ancestor::div[@id="refStash"]]
//text()[contains(.,"REFERENCES:")]/following::text()[normalize-space()]
```

Output :

[image: 5nodes]

Or to get directly the whole text (you can `split` it afterwards) :

```
substring-after(normalize-space(//div[@id="refStash"]),"REFERENCES:")
```

Output :

```
Braunwald, Eugene, et al. Harrisons's Principles of Internal Medicine. 15th ed. McGraw-Hill, 2010. FDA.gov. Computed Tomography. Tramma, Simone, et al. "Helical CT Scans and Lung Cancer Screening." CDC NIOSH Science Blog. 10 Jan. 2011.
```

**EDIT** : After making some tests, to generate a list of dics, we can do :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

dic={}
dic["references:"]=[]

page = requests.get('https://www.medicinenet.com/cat_scan/article.htm')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

buyers = int(tree.xpath('count(//div[@id="refStash"]/br)+2'))

variables = list(range(4,buyers,2))
for var in variables:
    result = [el.strip() for el in tree.xpath('//div[@id="refStash"]/br[$var]/following::text()[ancestor::div[@id="refStash"]][count(preceding::br[parent::div[@id="refStash"]])=$var]', var=var)]
    dic1={"text:":result}
    dic["references:"].append(dic1)

print (dic)
```

Output :

```
{
  'references:': [
    {
      'text:': [
        'Braunwald, Eugene, et al.',
        "Harrisons's Principles of Internal Medicine",
        '. 15th ed. McGraw-Hill, 2010.'
      ]
    },
    {
      'text:': [
        'FDA.gov. Computed Tomography.'
      ]
    },
    {
      'text:': [
        'Tramma, Simone, et al. "Helical CT Scans and Lung Cancer Screening." CDC NIOSH Science Blog. 10 Jan. 2011.'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm expecting the result is in a list of dicts format which we mentioned above.

Comment: Post has been edited with a solution. The script could be optimized but I think that's a good starting point.:)